# How to detect scrolling for NSOutlineView?

Tags: cocoa, nsoutlineview

I've two NSOutlineViews shown side by side they contain the same number of rows (this is a prerequisite) and I need to synchronize them when user scrolls using mouse, keyboard or scrollbars so I see the same view portion (or rows).

I'm a newbie in the Cocoa land and I'm unable to find how this can be accomplished

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to get the clip view of the NSOutlineView's enclosing scroll view:

```
NSClipView * clipView = [[outlineView enclosingScrollView] contentView];
```

...and set its -setPostsFrameChangedNotifications: to YES. Listen for the NSViewFrameDidChangeNotification from that view and respond accordingly.

**Note:** The nomenclature isn't very clear. Most people's first expectation of -contentView: is that it returns the view being scrolled. The -contentView: method returns the scroll view's NSClipView whereas the -documentView: method returns the actual view being scrolled.

Comment: It doesn't work, when I expand or collapse the view nodes the notification is called but when I scroll inside the view the notification isn't called

Comment: The problem is not related to the clipView, but using NSViewFrameDidChangeNotification the notification is called *only* when you resize the view *or* expand items but *is not called* when you try to *scroll* inside the view. thanks

Comment: I could've sworn that was the solution I'd found a few years back. How about NSViewBoundsDidChangeNotification / -setPostsBoundsChangedNotifications:?

Comment: I've found this article http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSScrollViewGuide/Articles/SynchroScroll.html but I don't understand why the method is never called. Honestly I have not subclassed but simply set the NSViewBoundsDidChangeNotification inside my init method