# Get scroll bar position of an NSScroller on the fly

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, observer-pattern, key-value-observing

The purple rectangle is an `NSView`.  In its `awakeFromNib` method I call `[[NSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"nib" bundle:nil]]`.

The red rectangle is an `NSScrollView` aka `@"nib"`. This view includes the vertical scroll bar.

The green box is an `NSBox` nib which is selected by `NSCollectionViewItem`.

[image]

How would one observe and get the scroll bar knob's position on the fly when scrolling through a list (i.e. while dragging the knob)?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Might be better to specify why you want to do this. I can think of a few approaches for several different reasons.

Comment: When i click triangle `NSView` attached to `NSWindow` is displayed. Position is relative to clicked triangle, but when i scroll through list, it dosn't change position, which is logical. I would like to know position of knob, to perform closing of `NSView` if list item is out of view bounds and to change it's position.

I'm using Matt Legend Gemmell `MAAttachedWindow` class to show this window.

Comment: Ah. I see what you're looking for. The answer is the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077843/how-to-detect-scrolling-for-nsoutlineview