# Get list element bounds or frame on scrolling

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

this question is related to [Get scroll bar position of an NSScroller on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363728/get-scroll-bar-position-of-an-nsscroller-on-the-fly)

But now i would like to know how to get current position of list element (green rect)  on scrolling.
[image]

`[self bounds]` or `[self frame]` or `[[self enclosingScrollView] ...]` won't work for this kind of thing or i'm using it in wrong way.

**EDIT**

Inside frame of `[[NSScrollView enclosingScrollView] contentView]]` we see list of `NSBox`'s.
When i click on triangle of `NSBox` which is list element, instance of that `NSBox` is stored in `-activeTicketRow`, i've thought that i can then get `NSBox` coordinates inside `NSScrollView` frame when `[[NSScrollView enclosingScrollView] contentView]]` bounds changes, but after reading "View Programming Guide" i guess not.

I've added observer in `NSScrollView`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
    addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(updateConvMenu:)
    name:NSViewBoundsDidChangeNotification
    object:[[self enclosingScrollView] contentView]
];
```

​

and in `-updateConvMenu` i get coordinates of `[[self enclosingScrollView] contentView]`, so that's good.

**QUESTION**

No i would like to store `NSBox` (which triangle was clicked) from `[[self enclosingScrollView] contentView]` inside `-activeTicketRow` so i can then get it's frame coordinates in `-updateConvMenu` when `[[self enclosingScrollView] contentView]` bounds changes.

I think now this question is more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When scrolling through the list, i'm calculating whether the horizontal center of the selected item in the list does not go after a specific bounds, which overlaps on `[NSScrollView frame]`.

Answer (score 1):

Views are in a hierarchy. Ask yourself "position relative to what view/window/screen?" Then use NSView's various -convertRect:... or NSWindow's -convert... methods.

Comment: It should be relative to window.
When i use `[self convertRect:[[[NSApp delegate] activeTicketRow] bounds] fromView:nil]` where `activeTabTicket` is list element, i get good coordinates, but they point to original position of item and they don't change when i scroll list.

Comment: What's self? Are you sure you want window coordinates? If you're trying to use a popover window, you almost certainly want screen coordinates. In what coordinate space does your -activeTicketRow's -bounds live? Are you sure all this is what you think it is? I'll bet not.

Comment: I really think you need to study up on View Geometry http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Coordinates/Coordinates.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978-CH10-SW1 and view hierarchy http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Coordinates/Coordinates.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978-CH10-SW1 ...

Answer (score 1):

You can get the position of the content view by observing the `NSClipView`s (the scroll view's `contentView`) bounds by setting `- (void)setPostsBoundsChangedNotifications:YES`. Then just translate the coordinates to the view you want, when the notification occurs.

For the translation have a look at the docs Josh did already post [View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Coordinates/Coordinates.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978-CH10-SW1)